# maintain pageViews in global.asax (asp.net)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, global-asax

I need a function in global.asax file which gets called only once when user enter a page url. application_beginrequest gets called 50-60 times in a single page( as to render a page several requests go to server.)

I thought of a solution - I can write my function in global.asax and call it on page load of other pages but in that solution I need to call it in every page. I would prefer something which is to be done only in global.asax

Answer (score 0):

You could test the request url in the Begin_Request function:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Perform some test on the request url that suits your case:
    if (Request.Url.ToString().EndsWith(".aspx"))
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another variation on your approach would be create a subclass of Page which called your global method, or did the work itself and then have all your pages extend your class not Page directly.

```
public class AcmePage : Page{
     // override/subscribe to one of the page events
}
...
public class HomePage : AcmePage
```

If you are just trying to count page views it may be worth looking at the pre built analytics services available, like the free [google analytics](https://www.google.com/analytics). There are others around like CoreMetrics etc.